# Python syntax - use of variable before "for keyword"

Tags: python, for-loop

I came across a piece of code with this line in it:

```
for l, val in zip((l for mod in (self.time_model, self.pitch_model)
for l in mod.layers if has_hidden(l)), learned_list[2]):
```

The part I have a problem following is the syntax `l for mod in`. How is it please called to put varible before the `for` keyword, so I can google it, or can you guys explain?

Comment: It’s a “generator expression”, and that’s an unnecessarily confusing way to write that loop.

Comment: yea it is. I think people should try to keep their code readable.